# change gridview to render thead element

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have seen some other posts on how to get this working ... however none of them seem to be concerned with case where you have sublcassed the GridView as your own custom server control.

I am attempting to set these properties to get the GridView to render a thead element but I continually get a null reference exception. Any takers?

Here is the DatBind method I overrided

```
    new public void DataBind()
    {
        base.DataBind();
        UseAccessibleHeader = true;
        HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader; //<<-- NRE here
        FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
    }
```

I want this logic to be encapsulated within the GridView control and not externally set. We are trying to update this behavior and would have to add the code to set this up in a thousand different places if we took that approach.

Comment: Actually, you are not overriding DataBind, you are just hiding it by creating brand new method.

Comment: @Loki kriasus Pedantic but yes, you are correct.

Comment: Maybe try setting useAccessibleHeader=true before databinding, so that when it databinds it generates the appropriate sections?

Comment: @Brian not a bad idea. I gave that a try and no effect. I tested adding the code to the page_load before binding to the gridview and it works just fine that way ... I don't understand what I am missing here ... I even tried moving the code to the OnDataBound() event and still no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the pre render event is the best place to put this. The trick is that in some circumstances that ellude me, the HeaderRow property will be null so I just needed to check for null =(

```
    private void MakeAccessible()
    {
        if (HeaderRow != null && !AllowPaging)
        {
            UseAccessibleHeader = true;
            HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        MakeAccessible(); 
    }
```

Lol didn't occur earlier to me that sometimes it is null and sometimes it is not ... doh