# How to set class for thead element in a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to set `THEAD` Class for GridView and I came as close as having a `Thead` element without Class property and have class name I want to tr element. The reason is because PDF generator will look for a thead class name and generate table header on each page. PDF generator has problem rendering javascript sometimes so I prefer pure html and css on the page.

**Code behind apart from databind.**

```
GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
```

**Aspx**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="table-header-group">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Forename" HeaderText="Forename" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-CssClass="iClass" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Surname" HeaderText="Surname" ItemStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-CssClass="iClass" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<table class="gvPrinting" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="GridView1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-header-group">
            <th scope="col">Forename</th><th scope="col">Surname</th><th scope="col">DOB</th><th scope="col">Session Name</th><th scope="col">Password</th>
        </tr>
    </thead><tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">+++</td>
        </tr><tr>
```

What I want is:

```
     <thead class="table-header-group">
```

Comment: You might be able to use HeaderStyle. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.headerstyle.aspx

Comment: @Papa Do you mean this line HeaderStyle-CssClass="table-header-group" that I already have in the gridview? It only sets the class for tr and not thead element.

Comment: Sorry, seems it's the same thing. Wonder if you could add the class to the element in Pre_Render()?

Comment: OnPreRender. Oh yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250258/change-gridview-to-render-thead-element

Comment: Thanks, @Papa .. I had that code already .. Yes .. it adds a thead element .. but class property is still on tr ..

Answer (score 0):

in your page, add this CSS

.gvPrinting thead{ write the styles you need.. }

or in the document.ready event ,,

$('.gvPrinting thead').addClass('table-header-group')

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Vinay, seems like you read the title and wrote your answer. I was trying to avoid javascript as the page needs to be rendered by pdf generator and it works so slow when javascript turn on in pdf generator.  Thanks though.

Comment: Hi.. check the below solution.. hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood is u need to add the CSSClass for thead element in the serverside code and not by javascript or CSS....

for this, use the following code.. it is working for me..

```
        gridview1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader; 
        gridview1.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
        gridview1.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "table-header-group";
```

let me know if this works for you.. sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Hi @Vinay .. Thanks but i think i have those in my code sample  already .. I was setting CssClass in the aspx page and your example is in the code behind .. it should do the same job .. and it didn't work what i wanted .. however, i found a hack .. not a proper solution though .. it is to write out what i want using Caption property. Eg. gv.Caption = '<thead class="table-header-group"></thead>'.